# Clean url from queryparams and urlParams with javascript regex or react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex

I have to clean the url's from numbers and queryparams.
E.G

> /hi/1/2 --> must be --> /hi

> /hi?1111 --> must be --> /hi

> /hi/hello/how/are/you/1/1/1 --> must be /hi/hello/how/are/you

I ve done it with window.location.pathname but the numbers after the slash were still here.

I was thinking maybe in a regex or something like that?

Any ideas?

I also tried with some hooks of react-router but no succeed

Comment: If you are creating these routes, then please fix the source where these redirects happen.

Answer (score -1):

```
function formatURL(arr = []) {
  // Stop code if array is empty.
  if (!arr.length) { console.error('No array provided.', arr); return arr; }

  // Format each element inside the array, replace old array value with the new value, output the result.
  arr.forEach(e => { arr.shift(); arr.push(e.match(/[A-z/]+/)[0]); console.log('Formatted URL:', arr[arr.length - 1]); })
  
  // Return array with formatted URLs.
  return arr;
}

// Call function, provide an array of unformatted URLs to it as the argument.
formatURL(['/hi/hello/how/are/you/1/1/1', '/hi/1/2', '/hi?1111']);
```

Hi, perhaps this solves your problem? Also, *not to hate*, but you should read up on Regular Expressions before posting a comment like this, as there are already plenty of resources available on the internet. With that being said, hope it works for you!